# Xml attributes to string array

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

How to get all "cc" attribute values from below xml into a string array

```
<DD a="1" b="2" c="3">
   <D aa="11" bb="22" cc="33"/>
   <D aa="11" bb="22" cc="33"/>
   <D aa="11" bb="22" cc="33"/>
</DD>
```

Cases I tried:

```
foreach (XmlNode xD in DD) {
                        XmlElement getFDD = (XmlElement)DD;
                        for (int x = 0; x < DD.ChildNodes.Count; x++)
                        {
                            XmlElement XmlFV = (XmlElement)DD.ChildNodes[x];
                            stringArr[x] = XmlFV.GetAttribute("CC");                        
                        }
                    }
```

And

```
   for (int u = 0; u < DD.Count; u++)
                    {
                        getFDD = (XmlElement)DD[u].FirstChild;
                        XmlElement getFDD1 = (XmlElement)getFDD;
                        stringArr[u]=getFDD1.GetAttribute("cc");
}
```

I tried using foreach to loop through each node, i gave up trying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for .Net 2.0

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fname);

List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach(XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("D"))
{
    list.Add(node.Attributes["cc"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with LINQ2XML:

```
const string xml = @" 
    <DD a=""1"" b=""2"" c=""3"">
       <D aa=""11"" bb=""22"" cc=""33""/>
       <D aa=""11"" bb=""22"" cc=""33""/>
       <D aa=""11"" bb=""22"" cc=""33""/>
    </DD>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var res = doc.Element("DD")               // Get the root element DD
    .Elements("D")                        // Extract all sub-elements D
    .Select(e => e.Attribute("cc").Value) // Extract attribute cc
    .ToList();
```

Here is how to do it without LINQ2XML:

```
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));
IList<string> res = new List<string>();
while (r.Read()) {
    if (r.IsStartElement("D")) {
        res.Add(r.GetAttribute("cc"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `XDocument.Parse(xml)` would be enough

Comment: @I4V Thanks for the correction, I keep forgetting about the `Parse` method even in some of my production code.

Comment: dasb: I`m sorry i can`t use LINQ2XML, i`m using dotnet version 2.0. Is there a way to do using string array??

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq2Xml

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load(yourXmlPath);
String[] attr=doc.Elements("D")
                  .Select(x=>(String)x.Attribute("cc"))
                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Anirudh: I`m sorry i can`t use LINQ2XML, i`m using dotnet version 2.0. Is there a way to do using string array??

Comment: @Anirudh What about  `string[] attr` :)